# Trying to make an error in php file and its not working

Tags: php

I am trying to make an error in the code like in the video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ol6C0ETQqM&list=PLE134D877783367C7, I think the problem is in the mysql_connect

Code

```
<?php
$connect_error = 'Sorry we\'re experiencing connection problems.';
mysql_connect('localhst', 'root', '') or die ($connect_error);
mysql_select_db('lr'); or die ($connect_error);
?>
```

Comment: Are we supposed to watch 9 minutes video to get exactly what you want?

Comment: most requests are to remove, not add, errors

Comment: Didn't watch the video, but are you sure your host name is `localhst`? and you have a semicolon after `mysql_select_db`, remove that.

Comment: I am following video what it says I do and I am trying to make error and its not working. I am trying to make an error in localhost by not putting o example localhst.

Comment: My question is when I go to localhost/lr/index.php browser or host should display error and it doesn't show that's what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semicolon after `mysql_select_db('lr')`:

```
$connect_error = "Sorry we're experiencing connection problems.";
mysql_connect('localhst', 'root', '') or die ($connect_error);
mysql_select_db('lr') or die ($connect_error);
```